# Redis error about return type

Tags: c++, redis, return-type

I recently included a redis connection into one of my c++ programs. I decided to use the [redox](https://github.com/hmartiro/redox) library since it seemed easy to use and does not depend on the boost library.

I use the connection to insert a value into a list in redis. The command works most of the times, but sometimes I get an error message saying that `Received reply of type 3, expected type 1 or 5.` After extensive search, I found these return types in the [hiredis.h](http://osxr.org:8080/redis/source/deps/hiredis/hiredis.h?v=redis-2.4.17) header file. It seems like the library expects a `String` or `Status` reply type but receives an `Integer` type.

Unfortunately I was not yet able to find any information about what this means and how I can fix the problem. Especially the fact that the codes sometimes works and sometimes does not confuses me.

In my use case I insert a string value containing a json dictionary in [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) format (but essentially just a string) into a list. I am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with the way the string is composed as inserting the same string by hand via the `redis-cli` client works fine.

My code for inserting the message is:

```
redox::Redox rdx;
try {
    if(!rdx.connect("localhost", 6379)){
        cerr << "Could not connect to redis" << endl;
    }

    redox::Command<string>& c = rdx.commandSync<string>({"lpush", "queue_name", message});
    if(!c.ok()) {
        cerr << "Error while communicating with redis" << c.status() << endl;
    }
} catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "send_message: Exception in redox: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

The error that is printed is the one after the `!c.ok()` check.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is due to the fact that you use string as parameter to the response.

As mentioned in the [documentation of redox](https://github.com/hmartiro/redox#asynchronous-commands):

> This statement tells redox to run the command GET hello. The `<string>` template parameter means that we want the reply to be put into a string and that we expect the server to respond with something that can be put into a string

But that works because the example was using the "GET" command which is expected to return a string. In the case of the "LPUSH" command that you are using the return result is an integer as can be seen when issuing the command using redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lpush "test" test
(integer) 1
```

So you must use a response with an integer parameter, the complete list of the possible response as listed [here](https://github.com/hmartiro/redox#reply-types) is:

```
<redisReply*>: All reply types, returns the hiredis struct directly
<char*>: Simple Strings, Bulk Strings
<std::string>: Simple Strings, Bulk Strings
<long long int>: Integers
<int>: Integers (careful about overflow, long long int recommended)
<std::nullptr_t>: Null Bulk Strings, any other receiving a nil reply will get a NIL_REPLY status
<std::vector<std::string>>: Arrays of Simple Strings or Bulk Strings (in received order)
<std::set<std::string>>: Arrays of Simple Strings or Bulk Strings (in sorted order)
<std::unordered_set<std::string>>: Arrays of Simple Strings or Bulk Strings (in no order)
```

So something like this would do:

```
redox::Redox rdx;
try {
  if(!rdx.connect("localhost", 6379)){
    cerr << "Could not connect to redis" << endl;
  }

  redox::Command<int>& c = rdx.commandSync<int>({"lpush", "queue_name", message});

  if(!c.ok()) {
    cerr << "Error while communicating with redis" << c.status() << endl;
}}catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "send_message: Exception in redox: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Or if using a lamda:

```
redox::Redox rdx;
try {
  if(!rdx.connect("localhost", 6379)){
    cerr << "Could not connect to redis" << endl;
  }

  rdx.commandSync<int>(
    {"lpush", "queue_name", message},
    [](redox::Command<int>& response){
      if(!response.ok()){
        cerr << "Error while communicating with redis" << c.status() << endl;
  }});  
}catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "send_message: Exception in redox: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I did not spend any thought to the return value as it does not really interest me.